# GPU runs during the dev step out of memory

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu

I'm using the [Denny Britz implementation](https://github.com/dennybritz/cnn-text-classification-tf) of [Yoon Kims CNN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.5882) for sentiment analysis in slightly modified form (I added the word2vec approach, so that the weight matrix is not calculated from scratch).

With small datasets (like 10MB) it works fine, but if I try to train on datasets of size >50MB (still not very large) my GPU runs out of memory and throws the following error: http://pastebin.com/AMfYkpXZ

The GPU is a GeForce GTX 1080 with 8 gb.

I worked out that the error comes from the dev step/evaluation step:

```
def dev_step(x_batch, y_batch, writer=None):
    """
    Evaluates model on a dev set
    """
    feed_dict = {
        cnn.input_x: x_batch,
        cnn.input_y: y_batch,
        cnn.dropout_keep_prob: 1.0
    }
    step, summaries, loss, accuracy = sess.run(
        [global_step, dev_summary_op, cnn.loss, cnn.accuracy],
        feed_dict)
    time_str = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
    print("{}: step {}, loss {:g}, acc {:g}".format(time_str, step, loss, accuracy))
    if writer:
        writer.add_summary(summaries, step)
```

To be precisely, it comes from the `sess.run([global_step, dev_summary_op, cnn.loss, cnn.accuracy], feed_dict)` line.
If i comment out the whole dev_step, the training runs without throwing errors.

Do you have an idea why this error occurs and how I can fix it? Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
The whole code is available at: https://gist.github.com/pexmar/7b3d074825eeaf5a336fce406d8e9bae

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code? Also, are you changing your batch size when you use the larger data set?

Comment: Sure, I created a gist: https://gist.github.com/pexmar/7b3d074825eeaf5a336fce406d8e9bae

Comment: I did not change the batch size with larger data sets. But without the evaluation step it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the size of the batches you're passing in to `dev_step` compared to the size of batches you're running in `train_step`. You may have to evaluate the test set (which I guess is the same as `dev`?) in batches as well.